# formatting concatenated string to date format in one query

Tags: mysql

I have two queries and I dont know how to bring them together in one query.

**First query:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(D_STRING, T_STRING) FROM TAB_CRU WHERE BILD_ID = '05985957'
```

**Returns this:**
08.11.2011231459

**Second query:**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('5.16.2011231459', '%c.%e.%Y%H%i'), '%d.%m.%Y/%H.%m')
```

**Returns this:**
08.11.2011/23.14

The result of the second query is what I would like to have at the end

Thx

Comment: So, replace the date literal with the CONCAT result … where exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT  
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(D_STRING, T_STRING), '%c.%e.%Y%H%i'), '%d.%m.%Y/%H.%m') 
FROM TAB_CRU 
WHERE 
BILD_ID = '05985957'
```

Comment: When I tested this query I got result like this

Comment: result is 11.08.2011/23.08